# Browser extension temporarily get disabled in Mac OS if the machine went to sleep mode for a couple of hours and then starts again

Tags: browser-extension, crossrider

I created a browser extension in crossrider and installed in Chrome in a Mac Machine. If the system went to sleep mode for a couple of hours and starts again, my extension get disabled temporarily. Restarting the browser will solve the issue. Can anyone tell me why it is happening? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser are you referring to? What is the extension id? I can look into the issue but I think the matter is better addressed to the Crossrider Support team (support@crossrider.com). [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: In a Chrome browser on Mac machine and the extension ID is 64995